# Is there anyway to add a directive to a component in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components, haml

So I've created a component named %atom-copy and I was wondering if there is any way that I can attach truncate to %atom-copy

Is this possible in Angular Js? Also, I'm using Angular Js 1.5.9 in my application.

```js
app = angular.module("myApp", []);

# ---------------------------------------------------------- #
# Text - Copy

app.component 'atomCopy',
  template: """
  <p ng-transclude truncator> {{ $ctrl.text }} </p>
  """
  transclude: true
  bindings:
    text: '@'
  controller: ($scope) ->
    
# ---------------------------------------------------------- #
# Truncator

app.directive 'truncator', ->
  restrict: 'A'
  scope:
    truncator: '='
    href: '='
    isShowMore: '='
    isEllipses: '=' 
    maxCharacters: '='
  link: (scope, element, attributes) ->
    console.log "HI"    
    
    scope.isEllipses = scope.isEllipses ? true
    scope.maxCharacters = scope.maxCharacters ? "10"
    
    scope.ellipses = "<span>...</span>"
    scope.showMore = "<span ng-click='toggleShowMore()'>...shore more</span>"
    scope.readMore = "<span>...<a ng-href='href'>read more</a></span>"
    
    scope.markup = scope.ellipses if scope.isEllipses
    scope.markup = scope.readMore if scope.href
    scope.markup = scope.showMore if scope.isShowMore and !this.href
      
    scope.toggleShowMore = () ->
      console.log "show more"
      
    angular.element(element).append(scope.markup)
    
    console.log scope.element
```

```html
%main{'ng-app' => 'myApp'}
  -# scenario 1 (most ideal)
  %atom-copy{tuncator: '', text: 'This is an example of an ellipse'}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the codpen https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/gGbqoY?editors=1011

Comment: You don't need `%atom-copy{tuncator: ''` on the component element, if you are using `tuncator` in the component's template. And also you have errors in you code, you can see them in the console.

Comment: Something like [this could work](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMYOKE?editors=1011).

Comment: Why wouldn't you need truncator: ' ' though? Is it because I'm using           `ng-transclude truncator` ? Also what not sure what '<' does? can you elaborate a little more on that? I've never seem that used before?

Comment: Have you checked the link from my comment? In your example you don't even need to use `ng-transclude`.